# Count first time subscribers by week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table Subscriptions in PostgreSQL 10.5:

```
id  user_id  starts_at  ends_at
--------------------------------
1   233      02/04/19   03/03/19
2   233      03/04/19   04/03/19
3   296      02/09/19   03/08/19
4   126      02/01/19   02/28/19
5   126      03/01/19   03/31/19
6   922      02/22/19   03/22/19
```

For each week, I want to count how many new subscribers we had. A new subscriber would be any user ID who did not have a subscription entry prior to that week.

**edit** I've modified @fubar solution slightly to fit the date formating I'd prefer. One clarification I forgot to add in here, is I'd like to see weeks when there are `0`. How can I integrate `generate_series` into the query below so I can also see weeks with `0` subscribers?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_trunc('week', s.starts_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as week, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM subscriptions s
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s1 ON s.user_id = s1.user_id AND s.starts_at > s1.starts_at
WHERE s1.id IS NULL
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week desc
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, skip those extra parentheses and simply write `count(distinct s.id)` to make code clearer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the first subscription per user with the following query:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM subscriptions s
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s1 ON s.user_id = s1.user_id AND s.starts_at > s1.starts_at
WHERE s1.id IS NULL
```

You can then count the number of new subscribers per year / week with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.starts_at) AS year,
    EXTRACT(WEEK FROM s.starts_at) AS week,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM subscriptions s
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s1 ON s.user_id = s1.user_id AND s.starts_at > s1.starts_at
WHERE s1.id IS NULL
GROUP BY year, week;
```

Below is an updated query which combines my answer above with `generate_series()` and your preferred week date format.

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(date_trunc('week', w.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS week, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.*) AS count
FROM generate_series('2018-12-31', NOW(), INTERVAL '1 WEEK') w(date)
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s ON s.starts_at BETWEEN w.date AND w.date + INTERVAL '6 DAY'
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s1 ON s.user_id = s1.user_id AND s.starts_at > s1.starts_at
WHERE s1.id IS NULL
GROUP BY w.date;
```

Database Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b73AbU3KU6dsfTvXu3mzjz/1

Comment: Your approach works, thank you! How can I also see values for weeks with 0 new subscribers? Do I need to use `generate_series`?

Comment: Yes. if you want every week listed irrespective of whether there are new subscribers or not, you'd need to use `generate_series`.

Comment: Do you know how that can be worked into your query?

Answer (score 0):

I +1'd fubar's solution. It works on all RDBMS.

I'll just provide another approach, it's Postgres-specific solution due to `DISTINCT ON`

**Finding dates of users' first time subscription:**

```
select 
    distinct on (s.user_id)

    s.*

from subscriptions s
order by s.user_id, s.starts_at;
```

Output:

```
| id  | user_id | starts_at                | ends_at                  |
| --- | ------- | ------------------------ | ------------------------ |
| 4   | 126     | 2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2019-02-28T00:00:00.000Z |
| 1   | 233     | 2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z | 2019-03-03T00:00:00.000Z |
| 3   | 296     | 2019-02-09T00:00:00.000Z | 2019-03-08T00:00:00.000Z |
| 6   | 922     | 2019-02-22T00:00:00.000Z | 2019-03-22T00:00:00.000Z |
```

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE subscriptions (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  starts_at DATE,
  ends_at DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO subscriptions VALUES
  (1, 233, '2019-01-04', '2019-03-03'),
  (2, 233, '2019-03-04', '2019-04-04'),
  (3, 296, '2019-02-09', '2019-03-08'),
  (4, 126, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-28'),
  (5, 126, '2019-03-01', '2019-03-31'),
  (6, 922, '2019-02-22', '2019-03-22');
```

**Getting the count of new subscribers per week**

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhzw4KvANA6Mvi59NDTy3H/0

```
with first_time
as
(
    select 
        distinct on (s.user_id)

        s.*

    from subscriptions s
    order by s.user_id, s.starts_at
)
select gs.wk, count(ft.*) as new_subscribers_for_the_week
from 
    generate_series('2019-02-25'::date, now()::date, interval '1 week') gs(wk)
left join first_time ft 
    on gs.wk >= ft.starts_at and gs.wk <= ft.ends_at

group by gs.wk
order by gs.wk;
```

Output:

```
| wk                       | new_subscribers_for_the_week |
| ------------------------ | ---------------------------- |
| 2019-02-25T00:00:00.000Z | 4                            |
| 2019-03-04T00:00:00.000Z | 2                            |
| 2019-03-11T00:00:00.000Z | 1                            |
| 2019-03-18T00:00:00.000Z | 1                            |
| 2019-03-25T00:00:00.000Z | 0                            |
| 2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z | 0                            |
| 2019-04-08T00:00:00.000Z | 0                            |
```